# Some Filters not showing on some Categories in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, category, filter, sorting, drop-downs

Some Filters not showing on some Categories in Magento 2.4

As you can see in two images both are diffrent categories but Newest filter not showing in second image.

[image]

[image]

In some categories it just show only position in Drop-down not all of them.

Can anyone suggest me how to show all the option in drop-down.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There maybe a two possibilites:

1. Please check whether the attribute "newest" is assigned to the attribute set of that category.
2. There may not be products available with "newest" attribute

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please tell me how to check both the options as i am bit confused.

Comment: Newset sorting will work on product created_at attribute so it would be different so i think it would be showing.

Answer (score 0):

In category Display Setting Tab :

Available Product Listing Sort By section all the data is not select so it doesn't show all on front-end.

Check SS: [image]

After selecting all the options after reindexing it shows on frontend.